# How i can get blog info using site url in multi-site

Tags: multisite

How i can get blog info using site url in multi-site

for eg : if i give the site url as `http://a.somename.com` and this should return me the value like

Site Name

Site Tag line

Site Database Table Prefix

**Used Code**

```
$blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url("http://192.168.0.89/dev/sareepuram/ss/");
echo get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'blogname' );
echo get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'blogdescription' );
```

If i use the above code i get the details for the below link

```
http://192.168.0.89/dev/sareepuram/
```

I use wordpress multi-site

The below link is the main site

```
http://192.168.0.89/dev/sareepuram/
```

And this link is the sub site     `http://192.168.0.89/dev/sareepuram/ss/`

**My Code Page Looks Like Below**

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-load.php');

$blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url("http://192.168.0.89/dev/sareepuram/ss/");
echo get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'blogname' );
echo get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'blogdescription' );

?>
```

Comment: If you are using sub directory install then you should use `$blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url("http://192.168.0.89/dev/sareepuram","/ss/");`

Comment: @VinodDalvi Not Working Sir

Comment: Try echo `get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'siteurl' );`

Comment: i tried but i get the main site details only

Answer (score 2):

Use [get_blog_id_from_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_id_from_url) function to retrieve blog id from url and then use [get_blog_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_option) function to get information for that blog.

Example :

```
$blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url("a.somename.com");
echo get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'siteurl' );
echo get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'blogname' );
echo get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'blogdescription' );
```

Comment: Not Working For Me

Comment: What is it displaying? are you getting any error?

Comment: i have already tried using get_blog_id_from_url() function but no luck

Comment: I need the details for this site `http://192.168.0.89/dev/sareepuram/ss/`, but I get the details for the main site `http://192.168.0.89/dev/sareepuram/`. I used like this `$blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url("http://192.168.0.89/dev/sareepuram/ss/");
echo get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'blogname' );
echo get_blog_option( $blog_id, 'blogdescription' );`

Comment: Can you add your code in question so that it can help me to find out the problem..

Comment: I have added kindly check